# C# code to set iis version of virtual directory

Tags: c#, iis-6, virtual-directory

I am writing a function to create IIS virtual directory programmatically.
I am not able to set the version of the VD to 4.0.3019 through c# code..
Please help on this

Comment: tried setting process start info with the version...

Answer (score 0):

DropkicK is a tool for defining your deployment procedure fluently in c#. It has the capability to do what you are asking for.

The simplest way to bring that functionality into your project would be to import the [DropkicK nuget package](http://nuget.org/packages/dropkick) into a new deployment project.

It uses WMI deal with Virtual Directories, IIS Versions and AppPool Runtimes. [Browse the source on GitHub](https://github.com/chucknorris/dropkick).

Comment: Thanks a lot for all the replies!!